# Is it legal to bring Snuff, Cigarette and Medicines while Traveling to Dubai?

Tags: legal, airports

Someone ask to bring me snuff, Cigarette and medicines. While I am traveling to Dubai. But I don't know the rules of airport. Is it legal to brings these thing with me?

Comment: The answer for medicines will almost certainly depend on what the medicine is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dubai Airports Security & customs](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/security-customs) has the information (***added emphasis mine***):

> **Customs**
>
> Like all countries, we have rules about what you can and can’t bring with you. Everyone who arrives must pass through customs, so please check the list below beforehand. Some items can result in fines or, in cases such as narcotic drugs, imprisonment.
>
> **Personal allowances**
>
> - Gifts not exceeding AED 3,000.
> - Cash above AED 100,000 must be declared.
> - ***Maximum of 400 cigarettes, 50 cigars, 500 grams of tobacco.***
> - Maximum of 4 litres alcohol, 48 cans of beer.
> - ***Medication: A maximum three-months supply of medication for your personal use.*** Please include an original prescription from a registered medical practitioner. All medications should be in original packaging, and not expired. No psychotropic medicines are allowed (even for personal use, in small quantity and/or with prescription) without prior approval from the Ministry of Health.
>
> **Items you cannot bring into the UAE**
>
> - ***All narcotic drugs.***

You would want to be extremely cautious regarding medicine:

- that what is prescribed in your name is for someone else
- that what is sold over-the-counter in your location may not be within the UAE
- that the quantity exceeds what may be viewed as appropriate
- that what the UAE allows for *personal use* if not intended for you